# Determining When a Windows Reboot is Required

Tags: windows, security, patch-management, sms

We are using Microsoft Systems Management Server (SMS) & Inventory Tool for Microsoft Updates (ITMU) for the distribution of Microsoft Security Patches. We use the following command for installation:
PatchInstall.exe /g:0 /d /n /z:ws /c:15 /t:30 /m:"PatchAuthorize.xml"

After installation of a particular patch set, the balloon indicates a restart is required however, there does not appear to be any PendingFileRename associated with it.

In a custom utility, we are trying to determine if a restart is required after installing patches.

Since it appears this information is stored somewhere other than the PendingFileRename key, does anyone know where this information is stored? Is there another way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

I have used a utility called [WhyReboot](http://exodusdev.com/products/whyreboot) for similar reasons many times.  You might find a way to use that utility, or follow his footsteps through the MS KB articles he used.

> The simple, supported solution is to
>   record an entry that will allow the
>   file(s) to be copied, renamed, or
>   deleted after the system reboots but
>   before Windows loads (or any user
>   applications start.) It is this method
>   that most installer systems use.
>
> I've investigated the methods used to
>   request 'deferred' file operations
>   after a reboot. It's not that tough,
>   Microsoft provides sufficient
>   documentation on their website:
>
> ```
> * MS KB Article 140570
> * MS KB Article 181345
> * MS KB Article 184408
> * MS KB Article 228930
> ```
>
> There are other resources on the web
>   (see related links, below)
>
> I present to you the results of my
>   curiosity and investigations: The
>   WhyReboot utility.